# jQuery css left/right chosen by array

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, arrays

How would I go about doing something like this:

```
var positionY = ['left','right'],
    x = Math.ceil(Math.random()*2);

$('#foo').css({positionY[x]: 200});
```

Is it even possible?

Reason being I want to randomise the left/right.

I'm really wanting to use the brackets in the css function, any ideas?

**EDIT --**

---

```
$('#foo').animate({
   positionX[1]: 300,
   positionY[1]: 300
}, 300);
```

That's the sort of thing I'm after, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
var cssCfg = {};
//Added left/right style - Similarly add other styles and pass the config
cssCfg[positionY[Math.floor(Math.random() * positionY.length)]] = 200;
//cssCfg["top"] = 10;//somevalue
//cssCfg["bottom"] = 10;//somevalue


$('#foo').css(cssCfg);

var animCfg = {};
animCfg[positionX[1]] = 300;
animCfg[positionY[1]] = 300;

$('#foo').animate(animCfg, 300);
```

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pQrV4/2/)**

Comment: How does that randomize anything?

Comment: @Amir - It was my fault, I edited the question after having posted it.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli What I mean is like `.css({ ... });`

Comment: @ShankarSangoli Yeah but I'm using .animate - I should of specified that. Also I'm doing another option aswell which gets the top/bottom.

Comment: You can add whatever styles you want it in the config. It is an object.

Comment: @tfbox - Check my edited answer, I hope now atleast you understand this.

Comment: @tfbox - I have added a link to working demo in my answer take a look.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli - Yeah it helped me do something I wanted to do thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
var positionY = ['left', 'right'];
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * positionY.length);

var cssStyle = {};
cssStyle[positionY[randomNumber]] = 200;

$('#foo').css(cssStyle);
```

Actually, I forgot jQuery `css()` also takes name/value pair, so the following works too:

```
var positionY = ['left', 'right'];
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * positionY.length);

$('#foo').css(positionY[randomNumber], 200);
```

Comment: Yar, the correct way to get a random number within a range :)

Comment: I would give +2 it it were possible -- one for the answer and one for using floor.